# RFC for definite integral connection to second derivative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Hi,

During my research I found an interesting fact, and I'd like to know if it's interesting for others as well.
Find a function $g(x,t):[0,T]\times[0,T]\rightarrow[0,T]$ such that for any twice differentiable $f(x):[0,T]\rightarrow[0,T]$ such that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, the equality
$$ f(x)=\intop_0^Tf''(t)g(x,t)dt$$
holds. Note that $g$ is independent of $f$.

I found such a $g$, and I'll post it as an answer soon. I'd like to know if this is simple/known/interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like a simple consequence, upon twice partial integration, of $f(x)=\int_0^T f(t)\delta(t-x)dt$, so your $g(x,t)=(x-t)\theta(x-t)$

$\delta(x)=d\theta(x)/dx$ relates Dirac delta function and Heaviside step function.

Comment: Hint: $g$ is continuous.

Comment: This $g$ is continuous.

Comment: so maybe I didn't get it.. doesn't Dirac and Heavyside discontinuous?

Comment: @Ohad: the product of $x-t$ and $\theta(x-t)$ is a continuous function with a discontinuous first derivative, $dg/dt=-\theta(x-t)$.

Comment: can you express it in terms of max/min?

Comment: $g(x,t)={\rm max}(x-t,0)$

Comment: I got $-min(x,t)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint ...
write $u(x) = f''(x)$, so that the condition is
$$
\int_0^T u(t) g(x,y)dt = \int_0^x\left[\int_0^y u(s) ds\right]dy
$$

Comment: I dont understand where $f$ comes into the picture

Comment: Fixed ${}{}{}{}$